# How to set not null property from typescript sequelize

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

Hellow, How to set not null property from typescript sequelize?
They have `@NotNull` decorator. but did't work that.
The errors are below.

```
Validation error: Warning \"notNull\" validation has been deprecated in favor of Schema based \"allowNull\
```

Be already set not null from MySql Scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @AllowNull instead of using notNull.
Reference:
https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript#model-validation